# GTM and wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I try to implement GTM in Wordpress theme editor the following error is showing and the file `theme.php` is not updating.

> Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the
>   PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change
>   by some other means, such as by using SFTP.

Comment: can you post your `theme.php` code?

Comment: Sorry that file is header.php

Comment: ok. can you post your header.php file code?

Comment: I have shared it in a google doc https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qQv78nyhr5zEhmihepr3x3lfLdC9c-_szvrY7WC5fsg/edit

Comment: I dont have access. ans sent the access request.

Comment: I have given you the access

Comment: I cannot see any GTM script in your code?

Comment: Please see that now

Comment: its script is correct. But seems you trying to update some other code. Can you share me the code which is you trying update

Comment: I've highited the GTM script in the header.php, i am only trying to add the script in the header and i am not trying to edit anything else, i am starting to think if its a permission where WP is not letting me edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins for GTM implementation on Wordpress. It's actually not good to have it implemented through the theme editor as the implementation is likely to be lost on theme switch or even update.